# Python in operator not working as expected when comparing string and strftime values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series, strftime

I'm working with datetime values converted to strings (years) in a dataframe. I would like to check whether a given year exists in my dataframe.year_as_string column using the `in` operator. However, my expression unexpectedly evaluates to False (see the second print statement). Why does this happen?

NB: I can probably solve my problem in a simpler way (as in the 3rd print statement), but I am really curious as to why the second statement evaluates to False.

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.to_datetime(['2013-12-31', '2014-12-31'])

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2], index=ind)
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['year', 'value']
df['year_as_string'] = df.year.dt.strftime('%Y')

# 1. the string '2013' is equal to the first element of the list
print('2013' == df['year_as_string'][0])

# 2. but that same string is not 'in' the list?! Why does this evaluate to False?
print('2013' in df['year_as_string'])

# 3. I further saw that strftiming the DatetimeIndex itself does evaluate as I would expect
year = ind.strftime('%Y')
print('2013' in year)
```

Comment: It looks like `df['year_as_string'])` is not a list like you're assuming it to be. (My first course of action would be `print(type(df['year_as_string']))`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `in` operator with a Pandas series will check the index, much like using `in` with a dictionary will check keys only. Instead, you can use `in` with a series' NumPy array representation:

```
'2013' in df['year_as_string'].values
```

A more Pandorable approach would be to construct a Boolean series and then use [`pd.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
(df['year_as_string'] == '2013').any()
```

Equivalently:

```
df['year_as_string'].eq('2013').any()
```

Even better, avoid converting to strings unless absolutely necessary:

```
df['year_as_int'] = df['year'].dt.year
df['year_as_int'].eq(2013).any()
```

Comment: This is quite confusing isn't it? Because list(series) will return the list of elements not of the index..

Comment: @Tillus, Yes, it's deceptive. In my opinion `in` operator should check values. To check index, better to use `in` with `index` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

In your second statement it checks the index numbers and not the values of the column. If you want to check the values you can use:

```
print('2013' in df.to_string(index = False, columns=['year_as_string']))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`in` on a `pandas.Series` checks whether something is in the index, just like a `dict`. [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series-is-dict-like)

Comment: This is quite confusing isn't it? Because list(series) will return the list of elements not of the index..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to check if a string is inside a `DateTimeIndex`. `ind.strftime('%Y')` returns `array(['2013', '2014'], dtype='|S4')`.

Maybe your check should be: `print('2013' in year.tolist())`